# Autostart SSH after reboot

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I've installed Debian (6.0) on a server. It currently has SSH installed so I can connect from a remote host. The problem is that when I restart it, it shows the screen to log a user in, and can't connect via SSH.

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?

Comment: Do you start SSH manually now after each login?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is sshd not starting on boot?

```
update-rc.d ssh defaults
```

Should put the proper init scripts in place for you.  This will allow ssh to start on reboot.

Is this what you mean?  If not, what do you mean by 'when I restart it', what's 'it'?

Comment: Uhm, this might be the problem. I thought it was other thing. So, when i start the server, there's no need to be a user logged in? I'll try. Thanks a lot!